# PHP Warning: file_put_contents() failed to open stream: Is a directory in

Tags: php, warnings, file-put-contents

I've searched and searched, but can't find an example like I'm experiencing, everything works but just looking to get rid of all the warnings this bit is throwing in my logs:

```
$propertyData = $propertyDetail->data;
$displayAddress = $propertyData->display_address;

if ( $displayAddress != "" ) {
    file_put_contents( $this->tmpDirectory."/slugs/".sanitize_title( $displayAddress ), $propertyData->property_id );
}
```

The `$displayAddress` is being pulled from an API call, it returns and creates the necessary files based off it, screenshot:

[image: https://share.getcloudapp.com/2Nuyklxd (working properly)]

Yet my logs are full of these:

> PHP Warning: file_put_contents(/kunder/qzgb_2535/contem_4144/public/wp-real-estate-7/elementor-three-demo/wp-content/cache/idx_temp/slugs/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /kunder/qzgb_2535/contem_4144/public/wp-real-estate-7/elementor-three-demo/wp-content/plugins/ct-idx-pro/classes/IDX.php on line 390

I realize that states "failed to open stream: Is a directory" which leads me to believe there's an issue with using a variable for the filename, or am I missing something simple?

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: what do you get when you `var_dump(sanitize_title( $displayAddress ))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir This is the output https://share.getcloudapp.com/o0u84PWo so it is returning some as empty which is related to the warnings but I have the if(condition) in place? Maybe I'm checking the wrong value?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I fixed it by removing the sanatize_title() function which was working but file_put_contents() was not 100% liking the output, here's the updated:

```
$propertyData = $propertyDetail->data;
$displayAddress = $propertyData->display_address;

if ( $displayAddress != "") {
    $displayAddress = strtolower($displayAddress);
    $displayAddress = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $displayAddress);
    $displayAddress = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $displayAddress);
    $displayAddress = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $displayAddress);

    file_put_contents( $this->tmpDirectory . "/slugs/" . $displayAddress, $propertyData->property_id );
}
```